# Why don't the records I've inserted into a table through C# persist after the program is closed?

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I know I'm accessing the correct table, because if I try to enter a row that I previously entered manually into the table, it throws an exception of the primary key violation, etc.

I'm using a Command Object to insert the rows. The code snippet is below:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString);
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Queries (A, B, C) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", conn);

insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("0", textBox1.text));
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("1", "BCA"));
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("2", "CDA"));

conn.Open();
try
{
    MessageBox.Show("Rows affected are " + insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
}

if (conn != null)
{
   conn.Close();
}
```

So when I enter the same record twice, I get an exception as expected.
When I enter the record that I entered earlier manually through Visual Studio (in Show Table Data), I get an exception as expected.

But the rows I've inserted at runtime don't persist across multiple runs. Rows I've entered through the Server Explorer (Show Table Data screen) are visible at runtime across multiple runs.

There must be a copy in memory (for each run) that I'm modifying but not saving back. How do I do this?

EDIT: I have a data connection in the form of a .mdf file, which contains within it a table (Queries). The connection is represented by the Properties.Settings... string.

EDIT 2: The rows I insert at runtime are visible in the mdf file copied into the bin/Debug folder - this version is for some reason not copied back to the original 'master copy'.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server? Access?  Or a local database that's getting overwritten every time you build?

Comment: I want to be able to insert rows into my table, and have them stay there after the program ends. I have an on disk table to which I'm opening a connection and sending commands.

Comment: It's a SQL Server database (I followed the steps on this link http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p1.html)

Comment: I suspect you are actually inserting to a different file.  Is the database file you're viewing in Visual Studio in your project directory?  Does it get copied to the output directory when you build?

Comment: What's the connection string value?

Comment: @DStanley The file is the correct one - as I said when I insert a record that I've entered manually into the relevant file, I get the primary key violation exception. Very certain about this, can provide screenshots.

Comment: @DavidOsborne Connection string is as follows: Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ChatBotDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

Comment: What is the default schema of your account.  Could you be writing to a different table e.g. [user].Queries instead of dbo.queries?

Comment: @w0051977 How do I check the default schema? The insert command seems to be accurate - plus like I said in earlier comment it is definitely the table I'm viewing through the Server Explorer

Comment: @Kaizoku Check if there is a copy of the database under the bin\Debug (or whatever build config) folder - although you see the rows you manually insert at runtime, that does not mean that the database is not being copied each time you run the application and you are inserting into a copy as D Stanley suggested.

Comment: @Mark - I was a bit unclear I think. When I refer to manual insertion, I don't mean at runtime. I mean rows I've inserted into the table through Visual Studio's Server Explorer (in the Show Table Data window). These rows are visible at runtime. Also, there is a copy in bin/Debug of the .mdf file as you said. Thanks

Comment: @Kaizoku That is what I thought you meant.  When you manually insert, you insert into the "master" copy of the database in App_Data in the project folder.  When you run the application, that version is copied into bin\Debug, and it is the bin\Debug copy (which includes your manual inserts) that is used at runtime.  If you open the copy in bin\Debug with Server Explorer, you should see the rows you have inserted at runtime (assuming no other errors).  Sorry, I am probably not explaining this very well. Exactly what happens may depend on the build settings (copy if newer/always etc).

Comment: @Mark You're spot on. The bin/Debug version does contain the rows I insert at runtime (and the ones inserted manually). So this table should get copied back to the master, but doesn't for some reason. Any idea why this might happen? The setting for my mdf file is 'Copy Always'. Thanks for the insight

Comment: sidenote: use the `using` statement for all instances that are implementing the `iDisposable` inteface.

Comment: @Kaizoku No, the records should _not_ get copied back to the master.  If you want changes to the data in the BIN folder to stay there then change the setting on the file in the project to "Copy if Newer".  If you need to make changes to the "master" file then you can let it either overwrite the data or manually copy data from the BIN folder.  That's part of the process of working with local database files.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks. I wasn't aware copying back was expected of the programmer. Shall I remove the question?

Comment: @DStanley Would also appreciate getting pointed to some source which shows the right way to copy back to the master file. (Right way being machine independent, etc.)